# Why two key DES algorithm provides only 80 bits security

Tags: des

In the wiki link, it is mentioned that due to "chosen-plaintext" or "known-cipher" attacks, two key DES provides only 80 bits of security.

My question is how these attacks work and how did NSIT came up with 2<80> bits of security

Comment: Related: [Why is triple-DES using three different keys vulnerable to a meet-in-the-middle-attack?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/why-is-triple-des-using-three-different-keys-vulnerable-to-a-meet-in-the-middle) and [Meet-in-the-middle with checking complexity](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10068/meet-in-the-middle-with-checking-complexity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what happens with Double-DES, consider the [meet-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) (completely unrelated to "[man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)").

**Setup:** there is double-DES, where a data block is encrypted with key *K<sub>1</sub>*, then again with *K<sub>2</sub>*. The attacker could have access to two plaintext/ciphertext blocks: attacker knows *A*, *B*, *C = E<sub>K<sub>2</sub></sub>(E<sub>K<sub>1</sub></sub>(A))* and *D = E<sub>K<sub>2</sub></sub>(E<sub>K<sub>1</sub></sub>(B))*.

Then the attacker can compute all *E<sub>K</sub>(A)* for all values of *K* (there are 2<sup>56</sup> of them). Then he can also compute all *D<sub>K'</sub>(C)* for all values of *K'* (again, 2<sup>56</sup> keys to try). At that point, he will have about 2<sup>48</sup> candidates for the *(K<sub>1</sub>,K<sub>2</sub>)* pair: these are all the pairs *(K,K')* for which *E<sub>K</sub>(A) = D<sub>K'</sub>(C)*. The "2<sup>48</sup>" comes from the fact that we are encrypting 64-bit blocks, so about 1 block value every 256 is one of the *E<sub>K</sub>(A)* values, so about 1 value *K'* every 256 will yield a matching *D<sub>K'</sub>(C)*.

The 2<sup>48</sup> candidates can then be tried with the plaintext *B* and ciphertext *D*; it is expected that only the right one will pass that test.

**Cost:** 2<sup>57</sup> invocations of DES (plus an extra average of 2<sup>48</sup> for the verification of candidates, but that's negligible), and some memory storage able to hold 2<sup>56</sup> intermediate values, and sorted. Since the values are sorted, each will differ from the previous by only 8 bits on average, but it must also store the corresponding *K*, so let's say that a practical implementation would use 10 bytes per value. That's then 10*2<sup>56</sup> bytes of storage, which is rather large (about 650 thousands of *terabytes*) but can be envisioned with existing technology (it would not be cheap, though). The sorting step would be the biggest cost in an "academic" way (about 2<sup>64</sup> comparisons) but the 2<sup>57</sup> DES invocations would still be, in practice, more expensive.

I don't see any "80 bits" here. In fact, **security of Double-DES should be considered to be close to "57 bits"**. The storage requirements make it harder to break than a simple "57-bit block cipher", but nowhere near as hard as an 80-bit block cipher.

(A similar method works for 3DES, which means that 3DES has security "about 112 bits" despite its 168 bits of key.)

Answer (score 0):

The thing with 80 bits security doesn't apply to Double-DES but to one option of 3DES.

If you use 3DES with three different keys you end up with 112 (and not 168!) bit security because of the meet-in-the-middle attack Thomas Pornin mentioned in his answer.

If you use 3DES with k_1 = k_3 and put some assumptions in then you end up with 80 bits.

Wikipedia refers to this pdf by NIST for:
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57-Part1-revised2_Mar08-2007.pdf